# Where to put "general" functions in Android?

Tags: java, android, function, package

I want to write a general function for my project that will be used across many different files and I don't want to have it in a particular class.

Where am I supposed to put it?
Inside a new package as a class?

Is this the only option?

Comment: Yes. That is the only option. Package with yourpackagename.utility or something. Then a new class and then all general functions will be in that class

Comment: In a language like C#, you could use [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) to accomplish something like this. In C++, you could use macros. What's so bad about putting the methods inside a class in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new package as util and create all common methods in there, for example:

Create package as `com.xyz.util`.

Create a class as `Util` in above package.

Then write your all common methods in this `Util` class.

You can write static methods in this class and access them as `Util.method_name();`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java every method lives in a class. So yes, its the only option. A common approach is to use a utility class containing only static methods. You can use it from everywhere without creating any instances.